# GlassMapper Returning Null for Item Template Information

Tags: glass-mapper

After upgrading to Sitecore 9.3 and GlassMapper 5+ the TemplateId and TemplateName are coming back as nulls. The item is retrieved using `MvcCurrentContext.GetContextItem`

```
TemplateId: {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
TemplateName: null
```

The item model is generated as follows. Are there new settings for 5?

```
[SitecoreType(TemplateId=TestPage_PageConstants.TemplateIdString )]
```

Comment: Is you property `virtual`?

Comment: Found when adding virtual to the template defintion it worked. Now I just need to change that so it generates correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your property is `Virtual`, we faced the same issue in `Sitecore 9.3`, after adding virtual it resolved for us. eg -

```
public virtual string Title { get; set; }
```

Comment: Found when adding virtual to the template defintion it worked. Now I just need to change that so it generates correctly.